# FrameworkExtensions Unable to Debug

Tags: spfx, spfx-extensions

Followed the steps in the below link to create a simple Framework Extension

```
https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/extensions/get-started/build-a-hello-world-extension
```

Observed Behavior

Unable to get debugging to work , (Not receieving the 'Allow Debug Manifest' Pop up and no alerts!).No paremeters are being encoded in the url and No Errors in command 'gulp serve --nobrowser'
Below is the url that I am appending along with my

```
 List/DocLib Url?loadSPFX=true&debugManifestsFile=https://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js&customActions={"9c43dad8-b79b-4221-83d3-837b3d562fe6":{"location":"ClientSideExtension.ApplicationCustomizer","properties":{"testMessage":"Hello as property!"}}}
```

Any ideas on what could be wrong here?

Comment: what type of tenant are you using ?

Comment: Office 365 Developer Tenant

Comment: It will work only on modern list and not on classic list view. Are you using the modern list view ? the full url would be somewhat like `https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/Lists/TestList/AllItems.aspx?loadSPFX=true&debugManifestsFile=https://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js&customActions={"9c43dad8-b79b-4221-83d3-837b3d562fe6":{"location":"ClientSideExtension.ApplicationCustomizer","properties":{"testMessage":"Hello as property!"}}}`

Comment: Yes mordern list view is being used.

Comment: sry my mistake the tenant was not a developer tenant and it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, currently SPFx extensions are currently in preview mode and are not production ready. You can test them only in Developer tenants. It will be available later across other tenants when they reach general availability.

Reference - [SPFx extensions overview](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions)

Comment: @jaj - can you please accept it as answer, so it wont show up in the unanswered section ? Its just a checkmark besides this answer. Thanks !